# engine speeds on startup (wont idle) after sitting for years - 1986 honda civic

Tags: engine, idle

Engine speeds on startup (wont idle) after sitting for years - 1986 honda civic.
As soon as I turn the key on it will keep speeding up higher & higher.

Answer (score 1):

Check your throttle linkage, make sure the throttle plate is returning to idle. Look for vacuum leaks on all the hoses. The Car is idling high because it's getting too much air